# how to get protractor running with firefox?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Trying to run a protractor test with the firefox browser. This is my config file:

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  //directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },

  //chromeOnly:false,

  // Framework to use. Jasmine 2 is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['example_spec_backup.js'],

  seleniumServerJar: 'C:/Users/myname/protractor/protractor-master/chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar',

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://www.angularjs.org/ : retries looking for angular exceeded.

This is one of the tests:

```
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');

    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });
```

When I start the test firefox goes to the angularjs.org but somehow the test returns an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the protractor referenceConfig.js

To connect directly to Drivers 
Boolean. If true, Protractor will connect directly to the browser Drivers
 at the locations specified by chromeDriver and firefoxPath. Only Chrome
   and Firefox are supported for direct connect.

```
 directConnect: false,
```

Path to the firefox application binary. If null, will attempt to find
  firefox in the default locations.

```
 firefoxPath: null,
```

As you are getting Angular could not be found on the page

1.This may be because you're using an old version of Angular. which does not support Protractor.
2.You need some  way of waiting until not only the element is present, but Angular is loaded on the page.One thing you could just do is to manually wait until angular is present:

```
browser.wait(function() {
return browser.executeScript('return !!window.angular');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not starting the selenium server for firefox browser to invoke. Add below line in your config file before **capabilities** -

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

Hope this helps.